# Расширение функций в Ember Glimmer компонентах

Tags: javascript

В классических компонентах можно было не только переопределять, но и расширять функции.

Например, имея функцию определенную в плагине, можно было расширить подобным способом:

**Изначальная функция**

```
myFunction() {
  console.log('main action');
}
```

**Расширенная функция**

```
myFunction() {
  console.log('mod action');
  this._super(...arguments);
}
```

Что в итоге вывело бы при использовании:

```
 mod action
 main action
```

Есть ли возможность такое расширение делать в glimmer компонентах? 
Аналогичный `super(...arguments)` работает только в конструкторе.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оказалось все проще чем думал, но не додумался загуглить сам [super](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/super) вне контекста Ember.

Получается что расширение функции теперь будет выглядеть таким образом:

```
myFunction() {
  console.log('mod action');
  super.myFunction();
}
```